# Is there a way to stop Camera after QR code scan is done using instascan for javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, qr-code, instascan

I am trying to scan qr code using instascan for javascript. It's working fine on android, even scanning is happening on IOS, the scanner.stop() function switches off the camera but the screen goes black and we have to manually close the camera. After closing the camera and returning to the application we can see that scanning was completed.
Is there a way to stop the camera in ios?
Library: https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js
https://github.com/schmich/instascan/

[image: After scanner.stop() is called.]
Attached screenshot:

Answer (score 1):

After you define an object with name lets say : `scanner`;
you can use:

> scanner.stop()

and make sure that scanner object detect the id of video tag. then try to target the window's id, which the camera has been opened in i, and close it.